# add subview and setting frame causing code to lag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to optimize the code, for some reason `initWithRootViewController,  [self.view addSubview:fullStory.view];,` 
 and setting the frame to the view's superframe is the biggest performance hurdle. Any idea why and how to fix this?

For high res picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKUv.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu6Dq.png).

Comment: Your second image link is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what's going on exactly, but it looks like some "lag" happens when you access the `view` property of the view controller.

Since this is a lazy loaded property, it calls `loadView` and then `viewDidLoad`. Perhaps there is something in those methods that takes a while.

Also, we can't tell if `displayStory` performs ok because we don't know what it does.